# Change directory path set in a variable inside a file using shell

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to change  `${localstatedir}/lib/corei7`  with `${localstatedir}/lib/${PN}` where `{PN}` sets the value to `i586`.

```
sed -i ${D}${sysconfdir}/file.txt -e "s|${localstatedir}/lib/corei7|${localstatedir}/lib/${PN}|g"
```

it gives me parsing error in this command, what is wrong here..

Comment: Please show the exact error message.

Comment: Use `set -x` to see the command after variables have been replaced, that may help diagnose it.

Comment: Without more context, my guess is there is a missing forward slash for the input, where `${D}${sysconfdir}/file.txt` should be `${D}/${sysconfdir}/file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

The same line worked inside a shell function, Thanks @Barmar and @Eric Leung
I used it like this

```
do_install_append () {
    if [ "${PN}" != "${BPN}" ]; then
    install -d ${D}/${localstatedir}/lib/${PN}
       sed -i ${D}${sysconfdir}/file.txt -e "s|${localstatedir}/lib/corei7|${localstatedir}/lib/${PN}|g"
       fi
}
```